# Whats the difference between the "OK Google" function and the new "Google Assistant"?

Tags: google

I've had OK Google on my Galaxy S7 since I bought it. Now I see Google Assistant coming out. Whats the difference?

Answer (score 7):

According to [this](https://www.cnet.com/how-to/the-difference-between-google-now-and-google-assistant/), Google Assistant is a beefed-up version of Google Now (what you call "OK Google"). Google Assistant allows for better context to your requests and is designed for better integration with other devices.